# Update trigger is not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

i have the following trigger:

```
 INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO [BUCHUNG] (BOOKUID, BOOKVERNR, BUCHUNGSART_ID, VERANSTALTER, PERSONAL_ID, 
        OPTIONSNUMMER, BUCHUNGSSTATUS, PERSONENZAHL, SERIE, THEMA, STORNO, UPDATE_DATE, UPDATE_USER, BEMERKUNG, V_EMAIL, V_TELEFON,
        KOSTENSTELLE, SERIENBOOKUID, THEMA_ENABLED, ABTEILUNG, LIEFERRAUM, ABRECHNUNG, KSTR, RECHKONTO, RECHDST, URSPRUNG_ORIGINAL, ORIGINAL_ID)

        SELECT i.BOOKUID, '0', i.BUCHUNGSART_ID, i.VERANSTALTER, i.PERSONAL_ID,
        i.OPTIONSNUMMER, i.BUCHUNGSSTATUS, i.PERSONENZAHL, i.SERIE, i.THEMA, i.STORNO, GETDATE(), i.UPDATE_USER, i.BEMERKUNG, i.V_EMAIL, i.V_TELEFON,
        i.KOSTENSTELLE, i.SERIENBOOKUID, i.THEMA_ENABLED, i.ABTEILUNG, i.LIEFERRAUM, i.ABRECHNUNG, i.KSTR, i.RECHKONTO, i.RECHDST, i.URSPRUNG_ORIGINAL,
        i.ORIGINAL_ID


        FROM INSERTED i 
        JOIN DELETED d ON i.ID = d.ID
        WHERE i.BOOKVERNR <> d.BOOKVERNR


        IF UPDATE (BOOKVERNR)

        UPDATE b
        SET BOOKVERNR = i.BOOKVERNR 
        FROM BUCHUNG b
        JOIN INSERTED i ON i.ID = b.ID

SET NOCOUNT OFF;      
END
```

The Trigger copies an entire row with a new ID if a change in the original row happens. So far it works fine.
But something is going wrong, because PERSONENZAHL_EXTERN and RECHKST is not correct.

Look at the Picture:  [image]

The first row is the old row. The second row is the inserted row. I don't know what is wrong. Maybe you can help me with that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you expect instead of the values we see.

Comment: i copy the entire row, so in the new row it should be also "0" at PERSONENZAHLEXTERN and "000000" at RECHKST and not NULL. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert statement is simply missing those two columns. Add them and you will have your values.